# Is there a list of most common english words for indexing text for search?

Tags: search, full-text-search

Is there a free available list of the most common english words to remove from text for creating a search index?

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia gives the 100 most frequent lemmas: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English

That might be good for a start; the article provides some good references.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.sugarcrm.com/wiki/index.php?title=Overview_of_Full_Text_Stop_Words) are the ones (plus characters) used in SQL Server 05 noiseword list, i assume the 08 stopwords are simular.

And the MSDN on it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx)

Hope this helps